# Is it possible to filter published folers via Web Deploy in VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I was wondering if it is possible to filter elements (folders that are in the solution Explorer) published via Web Deploy (in Visual Studio 2010) ? 
I know that it doesn't help, but I select "Only files needed to run this app" in my project Properties.

I am asking this, because I have a few folders (source image folders, doc folders etc) I don't want to be uploaded on the server. Maybe are you wonderning why am I keeping all these folders in my Solution Explorer ? because I am using a versioning system (VisualSVN) that let me track all changes in all these files also. Moreover, they are more easily accessible via my favorite IDE :)

Maybe is there a better way to organize myself ? if you have best practices or advices, let me know.

Thanks for your help and advices (for my 1st Stackoverflow post!)

Comment: check if VisualSVN consider .net project's exluded files for versioning, if yes , just exclude them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the web application project file (.csproj or .vbproj) in an editor or from within Visual Studio itself (see this post).

Add an  and/or  element in the desired  element.

e.g.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
  ...
  <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022</NoWarn>
  <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>File1.aspx;File2.aspx</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
  <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>Folder1;Folder2</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

check the below link for more detail:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/04/22/web-deployment-excluding-files-and-folders-via-the-web-application-s-project-file.aspx

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked perfectly ! thanks Imran.
To let people know, each <PropertyGroup Condition=...> corresponds to one of the project configurations, so for my WebDeploy I just modified the corresponding <PropertyGroup...> adding a <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment> section.

Comment: i cannot yet, i must have 15 reputations to be able to click on +1, i'll do it as soon as i can